# React router private route with local storage?

Tags: reactjs

I have a private route component which I use in my app.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
      const userLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('token');
      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) => (
            userLoggedIn
              ? <Component {...props} />
              : (
                <Redirect to={{
                  pathname: '/login',
                }}
                />
              )
          )}
        />
      );
    };

    PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
      component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    };


    export default PrivateRoute;
```

When logging in I'm setting `token` to `localStorage` and redirecting to `PrivateRoute`. The problem is that here `userLoggedIn` is `null` although if I check DevTools `token` is there in `localStorage`.

I'm not sure what to do here. I'm using localStorage so that when the page is refreshed user still logged in. All the help will be appreciated.

Parent of Private Route

```
const Routes = () => (
  <>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HeaderContainer />
      <Switch>
        <>
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={HomeContainer} exact />
        </>
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  </>
);

export default Routes;
```

App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <div className={styles.App}>
    <Routes />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you show the parent of `PrivateRoute` component?

Comment: @ravibagul91 edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch/children-node):

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
>   Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

It looks like your Private Route is wrapped in a React fragment, which could be causing the issue. Does moving the routes outside the fragment fix things?

```
  <Switch>
    {/* <> // remove line */}
      <PrivateRoute path="/" component={HomeContainer} exact />
    {/* </> // remove line */}
  </Switch>
```